# zle reset-prompt not cleaning the prompt

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I have a key binding to go up by one directory (very useful):

```
# C-M-u: up-directory
up-directory() {
    builtin cd .. && zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N up-directory
bindkey '\e\C-u' up-directory
```

It works well, except that the prompt is not really reset.

Example, starting in a Git repo (`~/.dotfiles`):

[image]

After `C-M-u`, I get:

[image]

So, I'm well one level up (into `~`), but the **Git info is still there**, while not valid anymore -- I'm *not in a Git repo anymore*…

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to execute the `precmds` before resetting the prompt.

fzf's [zsh integration](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/f79b1f71b86651fe5656eab1c360781e19e97826/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L70-L77) does this:

```bash
# Ensure `precmds` are run after `cd`
fzf-redraw-prompt() {
  local precmd
  for precmd in $precmd_functions; do
    $precmd
  done
  zle reset-prompt
}
```

So, try something like this:

```bash
up-directory() {
    builtin cd ..
    if (( $? == 0 )); then
        local precmd
        for precmd in $precmd_functions; do
            $precmd
        done
        zle reset-prompt
    fi
}
```

Comment: not OP but it works perfectly. Thank you!